# not able to execute binary in unix

Tags: unix, hadoop

I am trying to execute cloudra-manager-installer in ubuntu 12 and getting the following error. I provided executable permission to this file by

```
hduser@Dell:~$ chmod +x cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
hduser@Dell:~$ ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
bash: ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin: cannot execute binary file
```

on doing  uname i am getting following result

```
hduser@Dell:~$ uname -a
Linux Dell 3.5.0-47-generic #71~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 22:05:41 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
hduser@Dell:~$ sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin 

./cloudera-manager-installer.bin: 1: ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

on running file i am getting

```
hduser@Dell:~$ file cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
cloudera-manager-installer.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem solved posting it here so that it can help others. My system was a 32 bit while file was of 64 bit so it was giving error. I run the following:

```
hduser@Dell:~$ file cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
cloudera-manager-installer.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

hduser@Dell:~$ getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

Comment: accept this answer (or @mightybs 's) to help people reading this post.

Answer (score 3):

Your uname from above shows a 32-bit system, but from what I've read on the Cloudera site you need a 64-bit system.

Comment: i downloaded cloudera-manager-installer when i checked it with file command i found it is a 64 bit executable file. Is there anything available for 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

you need to mark the file as executable:

```
chmod +x ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

Comment: i had already done it forgot to mention. Thanks, can you help me ahead.

Comment: could the file be corrupted?  What do you get if you type "file ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin"

Comment: I am getting this as output. Please help me out.
hduser@Dell:~$ file cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
cloudera-manager-installer.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Answer (score 0):

After making sure it is executable (chmod +x ...), then you should run the command with sudo.

```
sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

If you still get errors, I would double check your download.

Comment: thanks on doing sudo its still not getting executed. Please help me further

Comment: i added the output with sudo in the question above

Comment: Yeah, I'd try getting a new download.

Comment: i tried with a fresh download but still getting the same error.